# I have to make Voice chat App in Oculus. What Keyword should I google or How can I make it work in Oculus?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, oculus

I have to make Oculus App. And It need 'voice chat' system.
and I'm using 'Unity Engine'.

but I've found "My Oculus Quest 2 mic doesn't work with Link" like that.
with 'VR-Chat'

I can find 'voice recording & playing' in Unity.
but I have to find Oculus mic setting.

How can I Find it?
or Can I get the Keyword to google it?

---

I made button event messed.
Fix, and it's done.

Comment: Write down an answer and accept it yourself, if you want to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I use 'Microphone' class.
my record button has play method, and play button has record method.

And I fixed it right way. and It work.
My fault. lol.

Oculus also works with the ordinary way.